# How get AWS API Gateway & Lambda REST API to correctly handle a POST as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm setting up a Lambda as a webhook handler that receive data POSTed from a remote API.

As per usual, the external webhook is POSTing the data in the form:
`payload='SOME_JSON'` for example `payload='{"foo":"bar"}'`

How can AWS API Gateway be configured to *correctly* handle `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data POSTed from an external webhook, e.g., to correctly map the raw content string into a "form style" parameter name/value pair and pass the *value* (which is JSON) to the Lambda?

The problem is that AWS API Gateway, by default, tries to relay the **entire** *raw* string `payload=JSONSTRING` to the Lambda, but of course the `payload=` is not JSON, it's the form parameter name, so that generates a 400 error (body not in JSON format).

To test, I posted the same data to both the AWS API Gateway, and, so that I can see exactly what is POSTed from the webhook, also to `webhook.site` for debugging.

As shown below the in webhook.site screengrab, the raw data POSTed is in the usual webhook format, "parameter=value" eg `payload=JSONSTRING`, specifically: `payload='{\"arg1\":\"val1\"}'`

And as shown in the webhook.site screengrab, their site completely understood how to map that to a "parameter name" (`payload`) and the parameter value.

`webhook.site screengrab:`
[image]

The closest I've come is to get the API Gateway & Lambda to stop throwing 400 errors, by using API Gateway's "Body Mapping Template" to at least *force* the raw content "param=value" into JSON format using this body mapping:

```
{"body": "$input.body"}
```

as described in this helpful blog post: https://blog.summercat.com/using-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-as-html-form-endpoint.html

*(edit: that blog post was old, Body Mapping Template is not required, API Gateway now supports enabling "Use Lambda Proxy integration" on the Integration Request for the POST method which passed to the Lambda the full input object (headers, payload, etc) as JSON to get rid of the 400 errors. **But** the "body" key/value in the JSON is **still** not parse-able JSON, it is prefixed with the payload=")*

But the problem is the the Lambda event hash still isn't in a usable format it *still* includes the "payload=...(escaped string)" e.g.
`{"body"=>"payload=%7B%22arg1%22%3A%22val1%22%7D"

So I hope there is *some* way to configure API Gateway to do what the rest of the world can do, and map the POSTed raw content "payload=JSONSTRING" to a JSON object that is passed to the Lambda, such as {"payload" : "JSONSTRING"} or perhaps just JSONSTRING?